# Open Shift Angular 8 Application Out of Memory Issue

Tags: angular, openshift, angular8

I am using Modern Wep App image for openshift Angular 8 app but application is getting failed on "npm build" Out Of Memory issue.

Error Logs:

> /usr/libexec/s2i/assemble: line 62:   296 Killed
>   $NPM_BUILD subprocess exited with status 137 subprocess exited with
>   status 137 error: build error: error building at STEP "RUN
>   /usr/libexec/s2i/assemble": exit status 137

[Environment Variables Set in Openshift Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOUxq.png)

Comment: Try increasing your build memory: https://cookbook.openshift.org/building-and-deploying-from-source/how-can-i-increase-the-amount-of-memory-a-build-can-use.html

Comment: @WillGordon , thanks for the link. Unfortunately executing `oc patch bc/cookbook --patch '{"spec":{"resources":{"limits":{"memory":"1Gi"}}}}'` yields `Error from server (NotFound): buildconfigs.build.openshift.io "cookbook" not found`

Comment: Try replacing `cookbook` with the name of your BuildConfig

Comment: Did anything work?