# Openshift Online failing to build angular app, Out of Memory

Tags: angular, openshift, angular9

So I will prefix this and say that my issue is very similar to the one here: [Open Shift Angular 8 Application Out of Memory Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58066739/open-shift-angular-8-application-out-of-memory-issue)

I wanted to add a comment to the older question, but I am a new SO user and don't have enough rep yet...

So, my issue: I have created an Openshift Online free account to do some experiments and thought a good first step would be to just get a simple container running a basic web-app. So I have used the OS web console to create an app that is based off the catalogue option for Modern Web App (as I wanted to try out S2I). This I pointed to my bitbucket repo and made sure the secrets were all set-up correctly. Once I could see the builds pulling from the repo correctly in the logs I thought it was sorted; I am however seeing this in the logs and all builds are failing:

```
...
> ng build


Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/common : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/platform-browser : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/platform-browser-dynamic : es2015 as esm2015

Compiling @angular/router : es2015 as esm2015
Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
/usr/libexec/s2i/assemble: line 62:   291 Killed                  $NPM_BUILD
subprocess exited with status 137
subprocess exited with status 137
error: build error: error building at STEP "RUN /usr/libexec/s2i/assemble": exit status 137
```

All I have in the repo is what came from downloading the latest version of Angular 9 and running the standard `ng create-app` command. I have no idea why it would be taking up so much memory...

Having searched the issue, the linked question is the closest I found and any other source of advice seems to suggest the same fix. Now I have increased the memory limit for said Build Config up to 1GB and it still fails - it wasn't even getting past the compiling stages and onto generating the bundles before, so it has definitely changed the situation. I tried increasing the limit further but it seems that Openshift (or OS Online version) has a hard cap on 1GB of memory per pod, and to be honest, while it would be great to know if that would fix the issue, I'd rather figure out why something that builds on my machine in under 500MB of RAM is suddenly chewing up all it can find inside the container...

Hope someone can help, Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could try reaching out to community support to have them take a more in-depth look at your build: https://help.openshift.com/forms/community-contact.html

Comment: Same here while building the app from source on the free Online OS.

---> Installing dependencies
---> Using 'npm install'
/usr/libexec/s2i/assemble: line 62:   281 Killed                  npm install -s
subprocess exited with status 137
subprocess exited with status 137
error: build error: error building at STEP "RUN /usr/libexec/s2i/assemble": exit status 137

Comment: @WillGordon I have tried contacting OS support since your comment but they weren't overly helpful. It boiled down to: "You ran out of memory, it won't work".
I've been doing local dev instead for now, but I should try following up to see if they can suggest any workarounds or ways to reduce the image's build memory reqs. Though I'm not hopeful.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the issue and I've found a workaround. You could:

- build image locally

```
s2i build https://github.com/gorbunov-ia/Diaries-web.git -r master -e OUTPUT_DIR=dist/diaries nodeshift/ubi8-s2i-web-app:latest diaries-web
```

- add a docker tag

```
docker tag diaries-web default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.ca-central-1.starter.openshift-online.com/diaries/diaries-web
```

- login to an openshift registry

```
docker login default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.ca-central-1.starter.openshift-online.com -u $(oc whoami) -p $(oc whoami -t)
```

- push the image to the registry

```
docker push default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.ca-central-1.starter.openshift-online.com/diaries/diaries-web
```

- create the app from the image